# OneDrive files on-demand not working in latest windows 10 and OneDrive update

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, on-demand

OneDrive just stopped working. I've tried to sign out/sign in, tried to reset the client via `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset`, also installed the latest version of the client from [official website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/new-onedrive-sync-client-release-notes-845dcf18-f921-435e-bf28-4e24b95e5fc0), nothing helps. It keeps showing such modal message with the message that

> Files On-Demand requires a connection to Windows in order to show....

[image: The picture i see]

Can't even get where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching: Windows restart after latest update **helped** here. I'll just leave this answer here, in case anyone has such problem.

Comment: Yes, I found that that is the only reliable way to resolve the issue, but I often encounter that popup when my network connection changes unexpected, like I unplug LAN and go on wifi, or VPN connection drops and I switch to public wifi. Any solution less drastic than reboot would be great I tried restarting the CLDFLT service but that did not resolve the issue.